# Using fetch API with OOP php class - do i need a URL?

Tags: javascript, php, api, fetch-api

I'm trying to setup a simple Stripe payment on my Wordpress plugin. I've followed their documentation and they recommend using fetch API to get the server side paymentIntent response from a .php file like below.

```
fetch("/create-payment-intent.php", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(orderData)
    })
```

However, my plugin is built using OOP and the code is within a class so I'm guessing if i point to this file directly it wouldn't work as it first needs to be first initialised. Is there a way of using fetch to call a method in a php class? Or is it better to use AJAX to handle the above?

**Update**

This is the code Stripe have in their documentation which i need to run in create-payment-intent.php. However, in my case i want to run the methods in a class so using fetch() woudln't work.

```
# vendor using composer
  require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

  \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(getenv('STRIPE_SECRET_KEY'));

  header('Content-Type: application/json');

  # retrieve json from POST body
  $json_str = file_get_contents('php://input');
  $json_obj = json_decode($json_str);

  $intent = null;
  try {
    if (isset($json_obj->payment_method_id)) {
      # Create the PaymentIntent
      $intent = \Stripe\PaymentIntent::create([
        'payment_method' => $json_obj->payment_method_id,
        'amount' => 1099,
        'currency' => 'usd',
        'confirmation_method' => 'manual',
        'confirm' => true,
      ]);
    }
    if (isset($json_obj->payment_intent_id)) {
      $intent = \Stripe\PaymentIntent::retrieve(
        $json_obj->payment_intent_id
      );
      $intent->confirm();
    }
    generateResponse($intent);
  } catch (\Stripe\Exception\ApiErrorException $e) {
    # Display error on client
    echo json_encode([
      'error' => $e->getMessage()
    ]);
  }

  function generateResponse($intent) {
    # Note that if your API version is before 2019-02-11, 'requires_action'
    # appears as 'requires_source_action'.
    if ($intent->status == 'requires_action' &&
        $intent->next_action->type == 'use_stripe_sdk') {
      # Tell the client to handle the action
      echo json_encode([
        'requires_action' => true,
        'payment_intent_client_secret' => $intent->client_secret
      ]);
    } else if ($intent->status == 'succeeded') {
      # The payment didn’t need any additional actions and completed!
      # Handle post-payment fulfillment
      echo json_encode([
        "success" => true
      ]);
    } else {
      # Invalid status
      http_response_code(500);
      echo json_encode(['error' => 'Invalid PaymentIntent status']);
    }
  }
```

Comment: You cannot call a PHP class directly from a url.  You must first load the class and then construct it as you previously noted.  The simplest answer is to use a plain PHP file to construct your object.

Comment: could you show us `create-payment-intent.php` and be specific about why you couldn't invoke a method in a class (required) inside the file?

Comment: The create-payment-intent.php is the example Stripe give here: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment-synchronously

Comment: @jibsteroos see updated answer

Comment: @shaun, thanks. So why couldn't you run the methods when they are inside a class?

Comment: Because Stripe uses the fetch() function and directly calls a URL to run the file whereas I need to call a method in a php to run instead. I think @AlexBarker has already said this isn't possible so i think i may just create a plain PHP file instead.

Comment: `fetch()` is a bit like modern Ajax, it lets you asynchronously fetch resources, like e.g. `create-payment-intent.php`. Surely you can wrap the stripe script in a class on the server if that's what you want, and surely you can instantiate and invoke methods inside the class sans probleme.